# undefined method `scoped' for Model:Class with Formtastic and MongoMapper

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, formtastic, mongomapper

I'm having a hard time making MongoMapper & Formtastic work together.

In an effort to isolate the problem, I've created a dummy application with the bare minimum of code.

I have 2 main models (Cabinet & Device), with "many/belongs_to" relationship between them and a scaffolded controller for the Cabinet ressource.

When I load a very basic formtastic form (see below) with anything other than a simple "key"  field declaration, I get a "NoMethodError" exception in the controller, with the following error "undefined method `scoped' for Device:Class" refering to the line #4 of the _form.html.haml partial.

Any idea on this one? Didn't find anything useful through Google or StackOverflow...

app/models/cabinet.rb

```
 class Cabinet
  include MongoMapper::Document
  safe

  key :label, String, :required => true
  many :devices
end
```

app/models/device.rb

```
class Device
  include MongoMapper::Document
  safe

  key :label, String, :required => true
  belongs_to :cabinet
end
```

app/views/cabinet/_form.html.haml

```
= semantic_form_for @cabinet do |f|
  = f.inputs do
    = f.input :label
    = f.input :devices
  = f.actions
```

I did't include the scaffolded Controller, as I didn't touched the scaffolded code in any way.

Gem versions used :

```
Gems included by the bundle:
  * actionmailer (3.2.7)
  * actionpack (3.2.7)
  * activemodel (3.2.7)
  * activerecord (3.2.7)
  * activeresource (3.2.7)
  * activesupport (3.2.7)
  * arel (3.0.2)
  * bson (1.6.4)
  * bson_ext (1.6.4)
  * builder (3.0.0)
  * bundler (1.1.5)
  * coffee-rails (3.2.2)
  * coffee-script (2.2.0)
  * coffee-script-source (1.3.3)
  * erubis (2.7.0)
  * execjs (1.4.0)
  * formtastic (2.2.1)
  * haml (3.1.6)
  * haml-rails (0.3.4)
  * hike (1.2.1)
  * hpricot (0.8.6)
  * i18n (0.6.0)
  * journey (1.0.4)
  * jquery-rails (2.0.2)
  * json (1.7.4)
  * libv8 (3.3.10.4)
  * mail (2.4.4)
  * mime-types (1.19)
  * mongo (1.6.4)
  * mongo_mapper (0.11.2)
  * multi_json (1.3.6)
  * plucky (0.5.1)
  * polyglot (0.3.3)
  * rack (1.4.1)
  * rack-cache (1.2)
  * rack-ssl (1.3.2)
  * rack-test (0.6.1)
  * rails (3.2.7)
  * railties (3.2.7)
  * rake (0.9.2.2)
  * rdoc (3.12)
  * ruby_parser (2.3.1)
  * sass (3.1.20)
  * sass-rails (3.2.5)
  * sexp_processor (3.2.0)
  * sprockets (2.1.3)
  * therubyracer (0.10.1)
  * thor (0.15.4)
  * tilt (1.3.3)
  * treetop (1.4.10)
  * tzinfo (0.3.33)
  * uglifier (1.2.7)
```

Answer (score 0):

mongomapper doesn't have the "scoped" class method. It's a feature of ActiveRecord and Mongoid.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I in fact got i working with mongoid.
I'm still confuse tho, because I've seen quite a few links on Google stating that MongoMapper in fact works fine with Formtastic.
For now I'm still assuming I've messed up somewhere and keep searching.

Comment: also scoped is deprecated under rails 4 now.  but formtastic is still calling it for me!